# (How) Can I use Chrome's inspector to set breakpoints on files that use cachebusters?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, inspector

I'm trying to set breakpoints on a JS file but Chrome doesn't seem to recognize that the page is the same due to a cachebuster on the URL (e.g., &random=123).

How can I convince Chrome that the page is the same regardless of its URL params?

Comment: Why do you use cachebusters on files that you don't expect to change (since you want to set fixed breakpoints in them)?

Comment: Normally it does change (it contains both data and JavaScript), but I'm using Charles web proxy to map to a local file for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the following in your JS where you want a break

`debugger;`